# Can RxJavaErrorHandler prevent an error from crashing the Android app?

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm trying to suppress an error with RX plugin, but the app is still crashing. Am I doing anything wrong or plugin error handler is just for reporting and cannot prevent the crash?

```
    public void testClick(View view) {
    RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerErrorHandler(new RxJavaErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    final PublishSubject<Integer> hot = PublishSubject.create();
    hot
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Integer value) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    logger.info("Result");
                }
            });
    Observable.range(0, 100).subscribe(hot);
}
```

Comment: I think that it depends of the exception. If it's because you updating the ui outside the main thread it will crash (because it's not throw IN RX). What's the exception witch lead to the crash ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at _onError method in SafeSubscriber class you'll find :

```
try {
    RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().getErrorHandler().handleError(e);
} catch (Throwable pluginException) {
    handlePluginException(pluginException);
}
try {
    actual.onError(e);
} catch {
    ...
}
```

You can see that RxJavaPlugins ErrorHandler doesn't affect further error processing and it should be used to log/report errors